# Card puzzle involving four cards

Tags: puzzle

[image]

You know that all cards are either checker or stripped on the back and have either aces or deuces. How many cards must you flip to answer: is every card that has a checkered back an ace?

Comment: This puzzle is associated with the [psychologist Wason.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wason_selection_task) The interesting thing is how many people get it wrong.

Comment: I think the usual form of the puzzle asks which cards must be flipped, not just how many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two, namely the ones on the ends. You don't have to worry about the card that clearly doesn't have a checked back. And you don't have to worry about the ace you can see, because it's clearly not going to falsify the statement that all checked-back card are aces. EDIT: Note that the answer would be the same even if you didn't know that all backs were checked or striped and didn't know that all cards were aces or deuces. You have to worry about cards that might be checked-back and also not aces, and that's that.